# Open File in Folder doesn't work as it should

Tags: nautilus

When i download a file, and I click on the little arrow beside it (or right click on it) and I tell it to "Open File in Folder", it opens the folder but doesn't highlight the file the way Mac OS X or Windows do.

Do you know if  there is an option sojmewhere, or a software, that can do this? Or should I report a bug?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue occurs with mozilla, the bug has already been opened: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=417952

Comment: Issue with Chrome too, I think it's more of a global linux issue than a Mozilla/Chrome issue